# Slave to Send Data after Receiving Command using I2C

Tags: arduino-mega, i2c, signal-processing

I want to have my Slave Arduino to send signal to Master after the command was made. But the Slave Arduino does not proceeds to sending the signal after doing the command. What is wrong with my code?

**Slave**

```cpp
void receiveEvent(int bytes) {
  dir = Wire.read();    // direction
  dis = Wire.read();    // distance
  spe = Wire.read();    // speed
  eStop = Wire.read();    // 1 or 0
  Serial.println(dir);
  Serial.println(dis);
  Serial.println(spe);
  mov = true;
}
void loop() {
    Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
  if (dir == 1 && mov == true && eStop == false){
      motor.Distance(dis);
      motor.Speed(spe);
      motor.Forward();
       Wire.onRequest(requestEvent); 
      mov = false;
      fin = true;
    }
  if (dir == 2 && mov == true && eStop == false){
    motor.Distance(dis);
    motor.Speed(spe);
    motor.Reverse();
      Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
    mov = false;
    fin = true; 
  }

  else{
    motor.Stop();
  }
}
void requestEvent(){
    Wire.write(1);
    fin = false;
    Serial.println("sent"); 
}
```

**Master**

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>

const byte interruptPin = 2;
byte dir = 0;
byte dis;
byte spe;
bool upd;

bool state= false;

void setup() {

  Wire.begin(); 
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), emergencyStop, CHANGE);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}
void loop() {
       if( state == false ){
       dir = 1;
       dis = 30;
       spe = 2;
       Wire.beginTransmission(9); // transmit to device #9
       Wire.write(dir);
       Wire.write(dis);
       Wire.write(spe);
       Wire.write(0);       
       Wire.endTransmission();    // stop transmitting
       state = true;
       }
       if (state == true){
        if(Wire.available() > 0){
       Wire.requestFrom(9,2);   //6bytes from slave 9
          bool upd = Wire.read();
          Serial.println(upd);
        }
      }             
}      
void emergencyStop(){ // not working
  Wire.beginTransmission(9); // transmit to device #9
       Wire.write(0);
       Wire.write(0);
       Wire.write(0);
       Wire.write(1);       
       Wire.endTransmission();    // stop transmitting

}
```

Comment: Please wdit your question to include the full sketch

Comment: Typically Wire.onReceive(callbackFunction) is called once in the setup().

Comment: Serial print in the callback function can cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

found my solution for this. although not verified yet, but i removed Serial print and moved the Wire.onRequest outside of the if loop. and uses a ledPin for checkups

```
void loop() {

        Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
        Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
  if (dir == 1 && mov == true && eStop == false){
      motor.Distance(dis);
      motor.Speed(spe);
      motor.Forward();
      mov = false;
      fin = true;
    }
  if (dir == 2 && mov == true && eStop == false){
    motor.Distance(dis);
    motor.Speed(spe);
    motor.Reverse();
    mov = false;
    fin = true; 
  }

  else{
    motor.Stop();
  }
}

void requestEvent(){
    if ( fin == true){
      Wire.write(1);
     fin = false;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you should not do serial prints inside an interrupt service routine.